# Website differs local from hosted - Different rendering of Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, localhost

I've created a JQuery plugin which is creating an easy-to-use image gallery. The gallery looked just fine on my local server(I'm using Wampserver) and I uploaded it and it was rendered perfectly. Now a couple of weeks later they look like they should on the webserver, but not on my local. I've tried creating new documents, but they all render the same. Then I uploaded one of these documents and so it rendered perfectly on the webhost, but then again not on my local. Why's that? And how can I fic this problem? I couldn't find any information about this online and I'm sure of that there must be other people who have got this problem aswell. **NOTE: AS FAR AS I KNOW THIS IS ONLY HAPPENING IN GOOGLE CHROME! BOTH MY LOCAL AND THE WEBHOST USES THE SAME VERSION OF JQUERY!**

**Render Problem:**
In my gallery one of the transition effects is "slide". On my local they now slide more than what they should and they starting position is not where it should have been. If I slide from the right their position is a bit to the left of the starting position. But on the webserver they start on their normal starting position and they do not slide more than what they should.

**I've tried these "fixes":**

- Clearing my cache(CTRL + F5) on Google Chrome
- Creating new documents
- Trying it on IE10 (If that's the one Win8 is using) - **works**
- Clearing all webinformation(except browsing history) on Google Chrome
- Uploading it to the web - **works**

**My Questions:** Why doesn't it render it as it should on my local drive? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before, and had to install a Chrome extension to properly trash the cache. I used [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/fkpampcchocandlbgdffjaihmccjmlgk), though many should work.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried both click on it and then do a normal refresh, a "clear cache"-refresh and also closing the page clear the cache and then open it again. Thanks for helping me anyway.

Comment: You're sure it's Chrome only? Have you checked Firefox?

Comment: I just tried it in Firefox and everything is as it should be. So yeah, so far it is just Chrome.

Comment: definitely post your jQuery code then ... also specify which version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it works now. I don't know if Google just updated Chrome or not, but it works. If not, maybe I just needed to reboot my PC after clearing my cache.

Comment: @JonathanJ For future reference you might want to try opening a new Incognito tab in Chrome - this way your existing cache is not used. I have found this useful for testing changes. Hope that helps.